# Execute powershell script using HTML GUI

Tags: html, powershell

I have a powershell script to perform the health check and other details of the Storage arrays.

I need to provide one user input. As of now I am proving the input from powershell itself. I am planning to build a GUI using HTML5 where i can enter the input in Textbox to powershell script and process the script.

Can anybody please tell me how can I achieve this.?

Regards,
KK

Comment: This is interesting: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2166.how-to-add-a-graphical-user-interface-to-a-powershell-script-by-using-html-applications.aspx

Comment: One idea I have been personally exploring lately is setting up a Jenkins server then creating a project with parameters. Then a JNLP Jenkins Slave as a service on the server to execute the code on. With project based matrix auth and AD integration you can provide a website with access control that allows for these tasks. Joel Reed just did an excellent presentation on this and posted his materials on his [GitHub.](https://github.com/jlrd/ScheduledTaskReleasePipeline)